# Is "project in hand" correct?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, phrases, prepositions, writing-style

I am writing my MSc project report in English and I want to use the phrase

> "the project in hand"

as a title to a chapter where I will be introducing the project that was undertaken.

Is such an expression correct in English, will it make sense to the examiner reading this or will it sound bad or even not make any sense at all?

Comment: "the project at hand" is probably the idiom that you want.

Comment: I was actually trying out a variation on the expression : "the problem `in` hand". That is why I used `in`. In UK English the expression "the problem `in` hand" is correct as well. But will the expression "the project `at` hand" or `in` hand" make sense anyway? Is it correct?

Comment: I'm Canadian so I'm unfamiliar with UK usage and that sounds strange to my ear, so I'll defer to Gigili's answer below. :)

Comment: I never heard "project in hand".  I'm sure there's a dictionary somewhere that lists it, but to _this_ native speaker, it sounds very odd.  I strongly recommend using "project at hand" instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OAAD](http://oaadonline.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/in+hand#hand_1__305) says:

> The job, question, etc. **in hand** is the one that you are dealing with.

So *the project in hand* would make sense.