# What does the idiom "this is in hand" mean?

Tags: idioms, idiom-meaning

I saw this as a reply to someone's enquiry of a work status.

> "This is **in hand** and will be completed prior to the move rest assured."

What is the meaning of 'in hand' here?

Comment: It means that the work is in progress and the situation is under control.

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-hand

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is "project in hand" correct?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81416/is-project-in-hand-correct)

Answer (score 1):

In this case '[in hand](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+hand)' means that the work is in progress.

> - In process, being settled, as in *He was willing to give full attention to the matter in hand*.

The Free Dictionary